# How to cast child to parent class in c# generics

Tags: c#, generics, covariance, contravariance

I have an classes:

```
class AClass : CClass
class BClass : CClass
```

And I need to use them in follow code:

The POJO class:

```
class SomeObject<T> where T : CClass
    T clazz;
    setClass(T clazz){
        this.clazz = clazz;
    .....
```

controller class:

```
class ObjectExecutor{   

    private SomeObject<CClass> someObject;

    public ObjectExecutor execute(SomeObject<CClass> so){
        someObject = so; //exception when so - is the instance of AClass 
        return this;
    }

    public void build(){
        ....
    }
}
```

so when I try to implement it:

```
SomeObject<AClass> soA = new....
soA.execute(soA) //exception point
    .build()
```

In result I get the exception: `can't cast AClass to CClass`

So I need use something like:

```
class ObjectExecutor{   

    private SomeObject someObject; //without <> signature
         ..... ....
```

but 'c#' compiler does not allow this way.

## How to use Generic extension in 'C#'?

screenshots:

I have two classes that extends between:

[image: Button extend of Adapter]

Interface:

[image: Interface]

Implementing:

[image]

And point where issue is occurred:
1.

[image: class]

2.

[image]

Error:

```
Arg "1": the type conversion from "MyTest.Terkin.ActionElement<Ranorex.Button>" in "MyTest.Terkin.ActionElement<Ranorex.Adapter>" is impossible (CS1503) - C:\Users\Valeryi\Documents\Ranorex\RanorexStudio\MyTest\Recording1.UserCode.cs:60,23
```

Comment: This is hardly the  point, but I hope you eventually spelled Pinapple correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the matter of [variances and covariances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)

### [Covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier)

After discussing your problem inside the comment section I've realized that you need the covariance here as you are assigning more derived class than originally specified. `Pineapple.Given` waits `ActionElement<Adapter>` but you are trying to pass `ActionElement<Button>` and `Button` is deriving from `Adapter`. It means we need covariance here. As I already told you in the comment section, you can achieve covariance with generics using [`out`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier) keyword. **Note that only interface and delegate type parameters can be specified as variant** so in order to achieve that we have to create an interface and use it whenever we want covarience to be applied. Here's the code (your code from screenshots that I slightly modified):

```
    class Actions { }

    class Adapter { }
    class Button : Adapter { }

    // covariant generic interface
    interface IActionElement<out T> where T : Adapter
    {
        T GetAdapter();
    }
    // covariant generic interface implementation
    class ActionElement<T> : IActionElement<T> where T : Adapter
    {
        T adapter;
        public T GetAdapter()
        {
            return adapter;
        }

        public ActionElement(T adapter)
        {
            this.adapter = adapter;
        }
    }

    class Pineapple
    {
        IActionElement<Adapter> actionElement;
        Queue<Actions> queue;

        // note that I'm using the IActionElement interface here. Not the class that implements the interface like you do
        public Pineapple Given(IActionElement<Adapter> adapter)
        {
            actionElement = adapter;
            queue = new Queue<Actions>();
            return this;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // now it works
            Pineapple pineapple = new Pineapple();
            var pineappleClone = pineapple.Given(new ActionElement<Button>(new Button()));
        }
    }
```

---

### [Contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-generic-modifier)

It's a vice versa case, when you need to assign less derived class than originally specified.

```
    class BaseClass { }
    class DerivedClassA : BaseClass { }
    class DerivedClassB : BaseClass { }

    interface ISomeObject<in T> where T : BaseClass
    {
        void SetClass(T clazz);
    }

    class SomeRealObject<T> : ISomeObject<T> where T : BaseClass
    {
        T obj;

        public void SetClass(T obj)
        {
            this.obj = obj;
        }
    }
```

And then you can use it like you this:

```
ISomeObject<DerivedClassA> soA = new SomeRealObject<BaseClass>();
```

Comment: What are the difference between <T> and <in T>? I have compiler error when try to use '<in T>'

Comment: It is steel no working for me. When I try to execute code I have the exception 'Can't cast AClass to CClass'

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi  generic types with different type parameters aren't assignable by default. The in parameter gives you the contravarience - it's the ability to use a more generic (less derived) type than originally specified when assigning generics. There's a covariance that works vice versa it allows you to use a more derived type than originally specified.

Comment: Why I can't use `in T`?

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi typeof(AClass) != typeof(CClass) they're assignable, yes. But they're not the same class.

Comment: So why are you suggesting that I use `in T` if I can't use it in my case?

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi you said that you want to achieve this: SomeObject<AClass> soA = what? If you wanted to assign SomeObject<BClass> - there's no way. If you want to assign SomeObject<CClass> then it's a contravarience. Use in statement to achieve that. If you'd want to do vise versa - SomeObject<CClass> a = new SomeObject<AClass>(), I would suggest using out parameter for generic

Comment: Why I can use new SomeObject<AClass>, but "SomeObject<BClass> - there's no way", if `AClass` and `BClass` extends the same `CClass`?

Comment: You need to understand - a) I cannot use '<in T>' signature generally becouse I got compiler error 'unexpected sign'. b) I try use `ISomeObject<CClass> a = new SomeObject<AClass>()` and got the compiler error "can't cast AClass to CClass"

Comment: I mean you said that you want SomeObject<AClass> soA = new...  What's ... here? If you meant SomeObject<AClass> soA = new SomeObject<BClass>(); it's not possible. If you meant ISomeObject<AClass> soA = new SomeObject<CClass>(); - it's achieveble with contravarience. If you want to do this ISomeObject<CClass> soA = new SomeObject<BClass>(); or ISomeObject<CClass> soA = new SomeObject<AClass>() - it's achievable with help of covariance. P.S. Covariance goes with 'out' parameter, contravarience with 'in' '

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi just try to compile exact code I gave you as an example. I compiled it successfully. Do it yourself and then try to modify it for your needs.

Comment: One more time...forgot the BClass. I try execute: `ISomeObject<CClass> a = new SomeObject<AClass>()`. Not AClass = new CClass. Not AClas = new BClass, not BClass = new AClass.

Comment: I did add the screenshots with code. As you can saw - I get the instance in method like `new Element<AClass>()`, where method expects the object like `Element<CClass>`

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi I edited my answer respectively to your edits. Take a look at this and follow through. This is exactly what you need. And don't forget to define interfaces as arguments instead of the classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203846/discussion-between-gleb-and-valentyn-hruzytskyi).